# How do I get the checked radio button value using only React?

Tags: reactjs, radio-button

I have been searching stackoverflow (and other places) for ages now, but cannot seem to find any solution to my problem (or at least none that I understand and can apply to my code..).

We have an assignment for school where we are ONLY allowed to use React. I am using radio buttons and want to display the checked radio button, but I don't understand how this should be done.

I will paste my original code without a lot of different tests and I know this doesn't work, but I don't understand what I should add. With the original code I only get "5", which is the last value in the radio button group, whatever I choose to check.

Thank you!

```js
//Displaying value
render: function render() {
  return React.createElement(
    "div",
    { className: "hotelRating" },
    React.createElement(
      "p",
      { className: "rating" },
      this.props.rating
    )
  );
}

//Displaying the form
render: function render() {
  return React.createElement(
    "form",
    { onSubmit: this.handleSubmit },
    React.createElement("input", { className: "rating-input", type: "radio", name: "rate", value: "1", ref: "rating" }),
    React.createElement("input", { className: "rating-input", type: "radio", name: "rate", value: "2", ref: "rating" }),
    React.createElement("input", { className: "rating-input", type: "radio", name: "rate", value: "3", ref: "rating" }),
    React.createElement("input", { className: "rating-input", type: "radio", name: "rate", value: "4", ref: "rating" }),
    React.createElement("input", { className: "rating-input", type: "radio", name: "rate", value: "5", ref: "rating" }),
    React.createElement("button",{ href: true, id: "add" }, "Add rating")
  );
}
```

---

**Update**:
Since I was asked to paste my entire code, here it goes. 
As you can see I'm trying to build a hotel database using react for a school assignment. I'm not done with all parts yet, so I know that it's not only the rating that's not working. I'm also working on adding an "edit" function to the posts :)

```js
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Assignment 5</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="js/react.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/react-dom.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
  <div id="hotelsDB"></div>
  <script>
   "use strict";
   var HotelEntry = React.createClass({
    remove: function remove(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     event.stopPropagation();
     this.props.onUpdate({ remove: true });
    },
    render: function render() {
     return React.createElement(
      "div", {
       className: "hotelEntry"
      },
      React.createElement(
       "h2", {
        className: "hotelName"
       },
       this.props.hotelName
      ),
      React.createElement(
       "p",{
        className: "rating" 
       },
       this.props.rating
      ),
      React.createElement(
       "p", {
        className: "addressLine"
       },
       React.createElement(
        "span", {
         className: "bold"
        },
        "Address: "
       ),
       this.props.address 
      ),
      React.createElement(
       "p", {
        className: "website bold"
       }, 
       "Website: ",
       this.props.website && React.createElement(
        "a", {
         target: "_blank", href: this.props.website
        },
       this.props.website)
      ),
      React.createElement(
       "div", {
        className: "buttons"
       },
       React.createElement(
        "a", {
         href: true, className: "edit", onClick: this.remove
        } 
       ),
       React.createElement(
        "a", {
         href: true, className: "remove", onClick: this.remove
        }
       )
      )
     );
    }
   });

   var Form = React.createClass({
    handleSubmit: function handleSubmit(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     var hotelNode = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.hotelName);
     var addressNode = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.address);
     var websiteNode = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.website);
     var ratingNode = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.rating);
     if (hotelNode.value != "") {
      this.props.onItemAdded({
       hotelName: hotelNode.value,
       address: addressNode.value,
       website: websiteNode.value,
       rating: ratingNode.value,
      });
      hotelNode.value = "";
      addressNode.value = "";
      websiteNode.value = "";
      ratingNode.value = "";
     } else {
      alert("You must add a hotel name");
     }
    },
    render: function render() {
     return React.createElement(
      "form", {
       onSubmit: this.handleSubmit
      },
      React.createElement(
       "input", {
        placeholder: "Hotel name", ref: "hotelName"
       }
      ),
      React.createElement(
       "input", {
        placeholder: "Address", ref: "address"
       }
      ),
      React.createElement(
       "input", {
        type: "url", placeholder: "Website", ref: "website"
       }
      ),
      React.createElement(
       "input", {
        className: "rating-input", type: "radio", name: "rate", value: "1", ref: "rating", onChange: this.handleChange
       }
      ),
      React.createElement(
       "input", {
        className: "rating-input", type: "radio", name: "rate", value: "2", ref: "rating", onChange: this.handleChange
       }
      ),
      React.createElement(
       "input", {
        className: "rating-input", type: "radio", name: "rate", value: "3", ref: "rating", onChange: this.handleChange
       }
      ),
      React.createElement(
       "input", {
        className: "rating-input", type: "radio", name: "rate", value: "4", ref: "rating", onChange: this.handleChange
       }
      ),
      React.createElement(
       "input", {
        className: "rating-input", type: "radio", name: "rate", value: "5", ref: "rating", onChange: this.handleChange
       }
      ),
      React.createElement(
       "button", {
        href: true, id: "add"
       }, 
       "Add hotel"
      )
     );
    }
   });

   var HotelsHeader = React.createClass({
    render: function render() {
     return React.createElement(
      "h1",
      null,
      "Hotels"
     );
    }
   });

   var HotelsStockholm = React.createClass({
    showHeader: function showHeader() {
     return React.createElement(HotelsHeader, null);
    },
    getInitialState: function getInitialState() {
     return {
      items: this.getItemsFromLocalStore()
     };
    },
    buildItemNode: function buildItemNode(item, index) {
     return React.createElement(HotelEntry, {
      key: index,
      hotelName: item.hotelName,
      address: item.address,
      website: item.website,
      rating: item.rating,
      onUpdate: this.updateHotelEntry.bind(this, index) 
     });
    },
    handleNewItem: function handleNewItem(item) {
     var newItems = this.state.items.concat([item]);
     this.setState({ items: newItems });
    },
    updateHotelEntry: function updateHotelEntry(index, action) {
     var items = this.state.items;
     if (action.remove) {
      items.splice(index, 1);
     }
     this.setState({ items: items });
    },
    getItemsFromLocalStore: function getItemsFromLocalStore() {
     if (localStorage.items) {
      return JSON.parse(localStorage.items);
     } else {
      return [];
     }
    },
    componentWillUpdate: function componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
     localStorage.items = JSON.stringify(nextState.items);
    },
    render: function render() {
     return React.createElement(
      'div',
      null,
      this.showHeader(),
      React.createElement(Form, {
       onItemAdded: this.handleNewItem 
      }),
      React.createElement(
       "div", {
        id: "hotels"
       },
       this.state.items.map(this.buildItemNode)
      )
     );
    }
   });
   ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(HotelsStockholm, null), document.getElementById('hotelsDB'));
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Using pure JS not JSX? can you post your whole component?

Comment: @JyothiBabuAraja , I have not looked into JSX, it was not mentioned in the assignment so I had completely missed it :( Will look into it though! I have added the entire code to the original post above.

Comment: By using `JSX` your code will be quarter of existing code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arajajyothibabu/ur5bbsra/)

Check this code. I think this might solve your problem.

**Update:** The `findDOMNode` with `refs` may not give the accurate `radio` which is `checked`. So we are maintaining a `state` for `component` with `rating` value which is updated by function `handleChange()`, which in turn triggered for change in `radio` input.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Assignment 5</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="js/react.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/react-dom.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="hotelsDB"></div>
        <script>
                        "use strict";
            var HotelEntry = React.createClass({
                remove: function remove(event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    event.stopPropagation();
                    this.props.onUpdate({ remove: true });
                },
                render: function render() {
                    return React.createElement(
                        "div", {
                            className: "hotelEntry"
                        },
                        React.createElement(
                            "h2", {
                                className: "hotelName"
                            },
                            this.props.hotelName
                        ),
                        React.createElement(
                            "p",{
                                className: "rating" 
                            },
                            this.props.rating
                        ),
                        React.createElement(
                            "p", {
                                className: "addressLine"
                            },
                            React.createElement(
                                "span", {
                                    className: "bold"
                                },
                                "Address: "
                            ),
                            this.props.address  
                        ),
                        React.createElement(
                            "p", {
                                className: "website bold"
                            }, 
                            "Website: ",
                            this.props.website && React.createElement(
                                "a", {
                                    target: "_blank", href: this.props.website
                                },
                            this.props.website)
                        ),
                        React.createElement(
                            "div", {
                                className: "buttons"
                            },
                            React.createElement(
                                "a", {
                                    href: true, className: "edit", onClick: this.remove
                                }   
                            ),
                            React.createElement(
                                "a", {
                                    href: true, className: "remove", onClick: this.remove
                                }
                            )
                        )
                    );
                }
            });

            var Form = React.createClass({
        getInitialState: function(){
            return {
            rating: 1
          };
        },
                handleSubmit: function (event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    var hotelNode = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.hotelName);
                    var addressNode = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.address);
                    var websiteNode = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.website);
                    var ratingNode = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.rating);
                    if (hotelNode.value != "") {
                        this.props.onItemAdded({
                            hotelName: hotelNode.value,
                            address: addressNode.value,
                            website: websiteNode.value,
                            rating: this.state.rating//ratingNode.value,
                        });
                        hotelNode.value = "";
                        addressNode.value = "";
                        websiteNode.value = "";
                        ratingNode.value = "";
                    } else {
                        alert("You must add a hotel name");
                    }
                },
        handleChange: function(event){
            var currentRating = event.target.value.trim();
          this.setState({
            rating: currentRating   
          });
        },
                render: function render() {
                    return React.createElement(
                        "form", {
                            onSubmit: this.handleSubmit
                        },
                        React.createElement(
                            "input", {
                                placeholder: "Hotel name", ref: "hotelName"
                            }
                        ),
                        React.createElement(
                            "input", {
                                placeholder: "Address", ref: "address"
                            }
                        ),
                        React.createElement(
                            "input", {
                                type: "url", placeholder: "Website", ref: "website"
                            }
                        ),
                        React.createElement(
                            "input", {
                                className: "rating-input", type: "radio", name: "rate", value: "1", ref: "rating", onChange: this.handleChange
                            }
                        ),
                        React.createElement(
                            "input", {
                                className: "rating-input", type: "radio", name: "rate", value: "2", ref: "rating", onChange: this.handleChange
                            }
                        ),
                        React.createElement(
                            "input", {
                                className: "rating-input", type: "radio", name: "rate", value: "3", ref: "rating", onChange: this.handleChange
                            }
                        ),
                        React.createElement(
                            "input", {
                                className: "rating-input", type: "radio", name: "rate", value: "4", ref: "rating", onChange: this.handleChange
                            }
                        ),
                        React.createElement(
                            "input", {
                                className: "rating-input", type: "radio", name: "rate", value: "5", ref: "rating", onChange: this.handleChange
                            }
                        ),
                        React.createElement(
                            "button", {
                                href: true, id: "add"
                            }, 
                            "Add hotel"
                        )
                    );
                }
            });

            var HotelsHeader = React.createClass({
                render: function render() {
                    return React.createElement(
                        "h1",
                        null,
                        "Hotels"
                    );
                }
            });

            var HotelsStockholm = React.createClass({
                showHeader: function showHeader() {
                    return React.createElement(HotelsHeader, null);
                },
                getInitialState: function getInitialState() {
                    return {
                        items: this.getItemsFromLocalStore()
                    };
                },
                buildItemNode: function buildItemNode(item, index) {
                    return React.createElement(HotelEntry, {
                        key: index,
                        hotelName: item.hotelName,
                        address: item.address,
                        website: item.website,
                        rating: item.rating,
                        onUpdate: this.updateHotelEntry.bind(this, index) 
                    });
                },
                handleNewItem: function handleNewItem(item) {
                    var newItems = this.state.items.concat([item]);
                    this.setState({ items: newItems });
                },
                updateHotelEntry: function updateHotelEntry(index, action) {
                    var items = this.state.items;
                    if (action.remove) {
                        items.splice(index, 1);
                    }
                    this.setState({ items: items });
                },
                getItemsFromLocalStore: function getItemsFromLocalStore() {
                    if (localStorage.items) {
                        return JSON.parse(localStorage.items);
                    } else {
                        return [];
                    }
                },
                componentWillUpdate: function componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
                    localStorage.items = JSON.stringify(nextState.items);
                },
                render: function render() {
                    return React.createElement(
                        'div',
                        null,
                        this.showHeader(),
                        React.createElement(Form, {
                            onItemAdded: this.handleNewItem 
                        }),
                        React.createElement(
                            "div", {
                                id: "hotels"
                            },
                            this.state.items.map(this.buildItemNode)
                        )
                    );
                }
            });
            ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(HotelsStockholm, null), document.getElementById('hotelsDB'));
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This works like a charm! I am so thankful! I don't quite follow what's happening in the handleChange function though. Could you explain a little bit? If not, I fully understand. I will investigate further myself as well. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Do you have any idea why the checked radio button is still checked after adding an entry? I've been working on this but I suspect it might be because of the "normal" behavior of radio buttons where there usually has to be at least one chosen.

Comment: Actually we can clear radio selection after `submit`. Here is the updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/arajajyothibabu/ur5bbsra/1/

Comment: You are really saving me. Thank you!